# Height and weight Validation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a regular expression to allow a person to enter their height in the following format either
5'10  or  5'10" making the quotation marks optional for the inches. There also could be a space between the feet and inches like 5' 10 or 5' 10".
thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `/\d+'\s?\d+"?/` that will allow the numbers to be multiple digits long, requires the single quote after the first number, allows an optional space after the single quote and optionally selects the double quote.

Answer (score 0):

The following will ensure that the number of feet is no greater than 9 and that the inches are between 0 and 11.

```
/^\d' ?(?:\d|1[0-1])"?$/
```

If you wanted to make sure the person is at least 2 feet tall, for example, you can just replace the initial `\d` with the appropriate range.

```
/^[2-9]' ?(?:\d|1[0-1])"?$/
```

For weight validation, you can do something like the following, which will ensure the user enters 2 or 3 digits followed by "kg", with an optional space in between. This can easily be adapted for "lbs", or the units can simply be omitted, depending on your requirements.

```
/^\d{2,3} ?kg$/
```

I think you might benefit from [reading up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) on regular expressions and [testing them out](http://regexr.com/) for yourself.

Comment: can you please provide regular expression for weight validation